# Keeping track of sheets added and removed

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, com-interop

I'm working on an Excel addin and have hit a roadblock.

I wish to update a combobox with the sheets in the Excel workbook. Currently I'm able to do this with a foreach loop. However, this is limited in the sense it only picks up added or subtracted sheets when I run it. My addin looks tacky with a "refresh sheets" button and I would like to avoid that if possible.

Ideally I'd be able to databind the worksheet object to the combobox so it's updated on-the-fly without my intervention. However, my research has turned up that it doesn't support that. I haven't tried it, as I'm not in front of my dev computer until later, but I'm almost positive since it doesn't inherit IList it won't work as a datasource.

Has anyone done anything similar? I'd really like to get this thing working right.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Excel.Application object has a `WorkbookNewSheet` event that fires when a new sheet is added.  Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to have an event that fires when a sheet is removed.

You could put your combobox update code in the combobox's `DropDown` event.  It fires as the combobox is opening, and your code can update the combobox items before the list is visible.

Comment: This is great as well. I'm going to try both the recommendations (Doug's first since its more general) and I'll check whichever works best. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I like WarrenG's idea of the dropdown event.  If that works it seems ideal.  Otherwise I'd recommend using the workbook's Sheet_Activate event.  This fires when sheets are created or deleted, at least if it's done by a user.

In C# you need to instantiate the event and create a handler.  You can actually do this in the Form_Load event, so that when the form is instantiated the event handler is created.  You need to set references to Interop.Excel so your Form.cs code would look something like this:

So, your Form_Load event looks something like this:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace ExcelWorkbook1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Globals.ThisWorkbook.SheetActivate +=
                new Excel.WorkbookEvents_SheetActivateEventHandler(
                ThisWorkbook_SheetActivate);
        }

        private void ThisWorkbook_SheetActivate(object Sh)
        {
            //Fill your combobox here
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: I found the basic code [at this MSDN site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.sheetactivate%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank you, this is excellent. I'll be home in a few hours and I'll be able to test it. I'll keep you updated. I wish Microsoft would've gone over the sheet events better! One question though: can I create the handler in the ThisAddin.cs file so that it works always? Or maybe the main ribbon cs file? Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome.  Yes, you can create it in the ThisAddin_Startup event (I think that's what it's called) or anywhere that runs before you need it.  On another note, I edited my response with the link to the MSDN page that had the bulk of the code.  (I'm pretty slow with c#).

Comment: I ended up giving WarrenG the checkmark because his dropdown solution was more elegant. However, I wanted to still point out that using event handlers was eye opening and your code has it's uses for sure. Thanks again.